# Retrieve lat/long data based on search term - Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Is it possible to retrieve a JSON object of lat/long coordinates using a query term such as "Tesco", from within the Google Maps API?

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Would be happy to amend the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you want to do it. If you use [Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) library in a map, you can use `place.geometry.location.lat()` and `place.geometry.location.lng()` to get the desired values.

You can also use something like `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Tesco&key=myKey` to get the JSON response that contains lat/lng and other attributes.

You may need to be more specific with the search term as "Tesco" is too broad.

Comment: My idea is that I want to be able to pull all Tesco locations without pulling each one separately, is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Yes, see here: https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#TextSearchRequests